# building a long string to be passed to function as argument

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, concatenation

I am very new to programming with C++, I have

```
char INSERT_SQL[60];
```

and later in code

```
  INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO 'tempLog' ('temperature', 'humidity') VALUES ('";
  INSERT_SQL.concat(tempInC);
  INSERT_SQL.concat("','");
  INSERT_SQL.concat(humidity);
  INSERT_SQL.concat("');");
```

after the values of temperature and humidity are updated.

but I am getting error saying *`invalid array assignment`*

if I use `String INSERT_SQL;` instead of `Char INSERT_SQL[60];` then I get this error:

no matching function for call to *`'Connector::cmd_query(String&)'`*

how should I build a long array that of concatenating different variables together ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are indeed writing C++ (according to `Connector::cmd_query(String&)`). Thus, you can use `std::string`.

```
std::string INSERT_SQL;
/* later */
INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO 'tempLog' ('temperature', 'humidity') VALUES ('";
INSERT_SQL += tempInC;
INSERT_SQL += "','";
INSERT_SQL += humidity;
INSERT_SQL += "');";
```

Use `INSERT_SQL.c_str()` whenever a `const char*` is required for function call.

Comment: thanks that works except it is leading to incorrect mysql string

Answer (score 1):

std::strings are rather poorly designed and it's hard to build one.

However you have the old C function sprintf. This takes arguments and is extremely flexible, and provides an easy way to build a complex string such as an sql query. After the building the string (whichever method you choose) print it out to check that it is right.

You can then convert a character array string to an std:;string for passing about. std::strings are good for that.

Code looks like this

```
  char query[1024];   // give yourself plenty of space;

  int tempInC;   // I'm guessing these will in fact be integers, not strings
  int humidity; 
  sprintf(query, "\"INSERT INTO 'tempLog' ('temperature', 'humidity') 
          VALUES(' %d, %d);\n\"", tempInC, humidity);

   printf("%s\n", query); // take a look, is the string right?

   // this interface takes a plain char *
   Connector::cmd_query(query);

   // you can just assign to a std string if you want to keep the query
   //  string hanging about. std::strings are better than char buffers for
   // medium-length persistent strings.

   std::string savequery = query;
```